# How to click elements in lightbox using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to automate an e-commerce website, after i click 'add to cart' a lightbox will be displayed for user to proceed to view cart and to continue to check out.

Here is my sample code, i think my code doesn't find the button because the lightbox is still loading.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("qty").send_keys("4")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("add_to_cart_btn").click()
```

*Lightbox loading here*

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("button_primary").click() #for clicking the view cart
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Proceed to Checkout").click()
```

Comment: there's [implicit and explicit](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html) waits you can use.

Comment: Pick an element in the lightbox and wait for it to be visible in the "Lightbox loading here" area... does that solve the issue?

Comment: I'm quie sure that there is no such element with tag name `"Proceed to Checkout"`. Do you mean `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Proceed to Checkout").click()`

Comment: Andersson yeah, that's what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

use the explicit wait method

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Classname, "add_to_cart_btn")))
element.click();
```

Comment: this doesn't work. it says   File "C:/Users/RoyceS/PycharmProjects/testing/Regression Testing (Automation)/Test.py", line 49, in <module>
    element.click()